# Facebook Graph API - How to get the groupId from the group url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

If I have the url of the group ex `https://www.facebook.com/groups/angularjs.dev/` How to I get the group Id of it.

If I have a facebook page(`https://www.facebook.com/raspberrypi/`) I'm able to get the ID from `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/https://www.facebook.com/raspberrypi/`.

But this is not working for facebook Groups.

Comment: Not possible. You can not look up groups by their name.

Comment: This website [findmyfbid](http://findmyfbid.com/) is giving me the Id from the url `https://www.facebook.com/groups/angularjs.dev`.. So there must be a way right?

Comment: Only by scraping Facebook pages - which is not allowed without their explicit prior written consent.

Comment: Any thoughts on what could be the reason for not giving groups when they are giving for pages.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?